# Any way to pass a vector to some legacy API that requires an array reference of some size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

**Background**
I am using GCC, C++11.
Lets say I have a vector initialized with a common value, lets start with

```
uint64_t val = 100;
std::vector<uint64_t> vect(2, val);
```

Typically when I deal with interfaces (legacy work API) that require a pointer to some data, I pass the underlying array of the data by passing into a function

```
function_name ( &vect[0] );
```

I think vector has a vector::data method which also does this (I think).

However I am getting an odd error I'm not sure how to deal with (not sure how to properly cast or pass this vector correctly - assuming it is even possible at all).

Here is the compiler error.

```
cannot convert '& vect.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<long unsigned 
int, std::allocator<long unsigned int> >(0ul)' (type 
'__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<long unsigned int> 
>::value_type* {aka long unsigned int*}') to type 'long unsigned int (&)
[2]'
```

I was trying to pass it a pointer (in a sense) but it was actually expecting a reference to an array of size 2.  I've tried to pass in my vector in many forms of guess-and-check (don't judge me....)

```
&vect[0]
static_cast<uint64_t(&)[2]>(&vect[0])
// same w/dynamic and reinterpret cast (yes I know it ...not the best idea)
```

So I can solve the problem by creating an array and copying the data over using memcpy (my job only support certain std functions since we don't have the entire std library at our disposal...meaning no std::copy, etc).

```
uint64_t myArray[2] = {};
memset( &myArray, &val, sizeof(myArray) );
```

And I can pass that to some function and it does so happily and correctly (as far as I can tell by my test printouts).

Is there any other way to pass in or safely cast my vector into some function to clean up this compiler error? I am annoyed by the fact I have to create another variable and copy the contents over...hoping to avoid this if possible.

As requested, this is the closest I can show from the API signature is like as it is proprietary

Id is an enum.

```
template<typename T> inline void function_name(Id id, T&) {}
```

Comment: To be 100% clear, could you provide the exact signature of the function you're trying to call?

Comment: Indeed; `vector::data` should replace `&vect[0]` and it handles the edge cases (empty vector, evil `operator&`).

Comment: If the function declares argument as a reference this does not mean that you have to pass a reference to it. Pass a value and function will take reference from that value `function_name (vect[0]);` if the function was declare like 
`void function_name(uint64_t arg);` or `void function_name(uint64_t& arg);` or `void function_name(const uint64_t& arg);`

Comment: Think about what casting a *pointer* to a *reference* means. I guess what you actually want to do is either `api(*reinterpret_cast<uint64_t(*)[2]>(vec.data()))` - cast from "pointer to `uint64_t`" to "pointer to `uint64_t[2]`" - then dereference to get a reference of the expected type. Or, `api(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t(&)[2]>(*vec.data()))` - get pointer to `uint64_t`, dereference to get reference to `uint64_t`, cast to reference to `uint64_t[2]`.

Comment: @melak47 your answer worked, since you were the first to post something that immediately worked for me, you would need to put your answer outside comments for me to select yours if you so desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
using arr = T(&)[N];

template<std::size_t N, class T>
arr<T,N> as_array( T* t ) {
  return *reinterpret_cast<T(*)[N]>(t);
}
```

that is my best stab at it.

```
some_func( as_array<2>(vec.data()) );
some_func( as_array<2>(vec.data()+2) );
```

You know the data is laid out like an array.

The above code hides the reinterpretation behind a somewhat type-safe fascade, in that it doesn't force you to type `T` and get it right or break the program in unexpected ways.  You are just in charge of getting `N` right.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/601aefce8c7f6a0a).